# Stroke a CGPath on the edges only

Tags: swift, geometry, cgaffinetransform, cgpath

I'm making a game using Swift and I have a CGPath at an arbitrary angle. For now let's assume it's always going to be a straight line.

[image: line]

What I want to create is something like this:

[image: line2]

I already tried the very simple approach of stroking at a thick line width in black, duplicating the path, and stroking it again at a slightly thinner line width in the background color. This gives the right appearance, but it ends up I need the middle to be transparent.

I think this can be achieved by using transformations of the "parent" path (in the middle), but I'm not sure how to do it. A simple translation along a single axis won't work because the path is at an angle. I'm thinking I would need to calculate the slope of the path using its endpoints, and use some math to find a point a certain perpendicular distance away from the parent path. But I'm not really sure how to do this. Any hints, or is there another way to do this?

**EDIT**:
I did try to use CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath, but of course that strokes the entire path and I really need to create two edges only -- not the ends. I **don't** want something like this:

[image: path3]

Comment: Is your path just a single straight line segment?

Comment: Yes, it's a single straight line segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath) to create a new path that outlines your current path at an offset you specify (the offset is half of the `lineWidth`). Then stroke that new path.

#### UPDATE

Here's a function that takes a line segment (as a pair of points) and an offset, and returns a new line segment parallel to and offset from the original.

```
func lineSegment(segment: (CGPoint, CGPoint), offsetBy offset: CGFloat) -> (CGPoint, CGPoint) {
    let p0 = segment.0
    let p1 = segment.1

    // Compute (dx, dy) as a vector in the direction from p0 to p1, with length `offset`.
    var dx = p1.x - p0.x
    var dy = p1.y - p0.y
    let length = hypot(dx, dy)
    dx *= offset / length
    dy *= offset / length

    // Rotate the vector one quarter turn in the direction from the x axis to the y axis, so it's perpendicular to the line segment from p0 to p1.
    (dx, dy) = (-dy, dx)

    let p0Out = CGPointMake(p0.x + dx, p0.y + dy)
    let p1Out = CGPointMake(p1.x + dx, p1.y + dy)
    return (p0Out, p1Out)
}
```

Here's a playground example of its use:

```
func stroke(segment: (CGPoint, CGPoint), lineWidth: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(segment.0)
    path.addLineToPoint(segment.1)
    path.lineWidth = lineWidth
    color.setStroke()
    path.stroke()
}

let mainSegment = (CGPointMake(20, 10), CGPointMake(50, 30))
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(80, 60), true, 2)
UIColor.whiteColor().setFill(); UIRectFill(.infinite)
stroke(mainSegment, lineWidth: 1, color: .blackColor())
stroke(lineSegment(mainSegment, offsetBy: 10), lineWidth: 2, color: .redColor())
stroke(lineSegment(mainSegment, offsetBy: -10), lineWidth: 2, color: .blueColor())
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.captureValue(image, withIdentifier: "image")
```

Result:

[image: parallel line segments]

Comment: See my edit above. I tried this but I don't think it will work for my use case.

Comment: This worked perfectly and is much more than I expected. Thanks!